# How to get data Object using retrofit2

Tags: android

how to retrieve data with the fire response as quoted, using retrofit 2
if I check using `Log.v` the result is force close. I am confused that the problem is not explained there.

response api.

```
    [
      {
        "name": "Jono",
        "Alamar": "Jl Melburn",
        "umur": "19",
        "status": "sehat"
      }
    ]
```

get data:

```
private void getData(){

    mApiService.getData().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseData> call, Response<ResponseData> response) {


            Log.v("jajal", "LOGS" +response.body());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseData> call, Throwable t) {
           //// pDialog.dismiss();
           //// Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Keneksi terputus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });

}
```

log error

```
A/zygote64: thread.cc:2130] No pending exception expected: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6
    thread.cc:2130]   at void retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.onFailure(retrofit2.Call, java.lang.Throwable) (DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:87)
    thread.cc:2130]   at void retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.callFailure(java.lang.Throwable) (OkHttpCall.java:142)
    thread.cc:2130]   at void retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(okhttp3.Call, okhttp3.Response) (OkHttpCall.java:124)
    thread.cc:2130]   at void okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run() (RealCall.kt:138)
    thread.cc:2130]   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    thread.cc:2130]   at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    thread.cc:2130]   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
    thread.cc:2130] 
A/zygote64: runtime.cc:598] Runtime aborting...
    runtime.cc:598] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock
    runtime.cc:598] All threads:
    runtime.cc:598] DALVIK THREADS (20):
    runtime.cc:598] "OkHttp https://api.xxxx.com/..." prio=5 tid=12 Runnable
    runtime.cc:598]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x1b100910 self=0x72a5e6a800
    runtime.cc:598]   | sysTid=31579 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x72997cf4f0
    runtime.cc:598]   | state=R schedstat=( 479112865 17531404 115 ) utm=45 stm=2 core=0 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:598]   | stack=0x72996cd000-0x72996cf000 stackSize=1037KB
    runtime.cc:598]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #00 pc 00000000003cc138  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+208)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #01 pc 00000000004a0450  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+348)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #02 pc 00000000004b99bc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+964)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #03 pc 00000000004b1d80  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*, bool)+864)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #04 pc 00000000004b1350  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+304)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #05 pc 00000000004877bc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&) const+220)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #06 pc 0000000000475d3c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+196)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #07 pc 0000000000570348  /system/lib64/libart.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+996)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #08 pc 00000000004a4ed8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::AssertNoPendingException() const+1148)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #09 pc 000000000012e3b4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::FindClass(art::Thread*, char const*, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>)+64)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #10 pc 000000000011c718  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::ResolveType(art::DexFile const&, art::dex::TypeIndex, art::Handle<art::mirror::DexCache>, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>)+308)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #11 pc 000000000014b178  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::ResolveMethodHandleForMethod(art::Thread*, art::DexFile const*, art::DexFile::MethodHandleItem const&, art::ArtMethod*)+2116)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #12 pc 000000000029808c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::InvokeBootstrapMethod(art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, unsigned int)+408)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #13 pc 0000000000297c74  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter14DoInvokeCustomILb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+336)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #14 pc 00000000002ac590  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb1ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+62696)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #15 pc 0000000000276524  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+700)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #16 pc 000000000027c02c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #17 pc 0000000000295fa0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+664)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #18 pc 0000000000538cb0  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1528)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #19 pc 0000000000541a94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #20 pc 0000000000276424  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+444)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #21 pc 000000000027c02c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #22 pc 0000000000295fa0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+664)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #23 pc 0000000000538f1c  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+304)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #24 pc 0000000000541994  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #25 pc 0000000000276424  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+444)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #26 pc 000000000027c02c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #27 pc 0000000000295fa0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+664)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #28 pc 0000000000538cb0  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1528)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #29 pc 0000000000541a94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #30 pc 0000000000276424  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+444)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #31 pc 000000000027c02c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #32 pc 0000000000295fa0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+664)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #33 pc 0000000000538cb0  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1528)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #34 pc 0000000000541a94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #35 pc 0000000000276424  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+444)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #36 pc 000000000027c02c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #37 pc 0000000000295fa0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+664)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #38 pc 0000000000537d64  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+612)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #39 pc 0000000000541894  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #40 pc 0000000000276424  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+444)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #41 pc 000000000027c02c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #42 pc 0000000000295fa0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+664)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #43 pc 0000000000538cb0  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1528)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #44 pc 0000000000541a94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #45 pc 0000000000276424  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+444)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #46 pc 000000000052a934  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1052)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #47 pc 0000000000558d0c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
    runtime.cc:598]   native: #48 pc 000000000054fb88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
```

Comment: Are you using GSON converter

Comment: for the libraries I use it @NatarajKR

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onResponse(Call<R> call, Response<R> response) {
    String jsonData = response.body().string();
    try {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) result;
        String name = (String) list.get(0).get("name");
        String Alamar = (String) list.get(0).get("Alamar");
        String umur = (String) list.get(0).get("umur");
        String status = (String) list.get(0).get("status");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/rwwz9z not work, I tried using it before @Dilshod